# Google Sheets: Compare two dates by Year and count if same year

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I have the following data in google sheets (or excel). I want to compare the dates in column B and C to determine if they occurred in the same **year**, ***without** changing the format of the dates* or *adding the example column D below*.
Then, if they did occur in the same year, I want to count how many for that specific year.

```
A   B           C            D
1   7/7/2020    11/18/2021  (No)
2   8/25/2021   11/17/2021  (Yes)
3   5/27/2021   10/27/2021  (Yes)
4   12/8/2020   10/27/2021  (No)
5   3/27/2019   10/18/2021  (No)
6   1/25/2018   6/30/2018   (Yes)
```

What I am trying to show/count:
Year - Count
2021 - 2
2020 - 0
2019 - 0
2018 - 1

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I would say that it would probably be easier if you did change the format such that the dates for month and day always are two digits, such that you can isolate the year easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=query(ARRAYFORMULA({year(A1:A6),if(year(A1:A6)=year(B1:B6),1,0)}),"select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1")
```

[image]

If dates are in text format, use

```
=query(ARRAYFORMULA(
{REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A6),"[0-9]{4}"),if(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A6),"[0-9]{4}")=REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B1:B6),"[0-9]{4}"),1,0)}),
"select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1")
```

[image]

Comment: this will work only if OP's dates are valid: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl88b.png

Comment: Yes of course, but we don't have any requestor spreadsheet ... so we can't know if there is numeric (dates) or text. I just copied the values ​​as is to my spreadsheet and split them with a space separator.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B1:B), "\d{4}")=REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(C1:C), "\d{4}")))
```

[image]

and then:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IFNA({
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B1:B), "\d{4}"), ( 
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B1:B), "\d{4}")=
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(C1:C), "\d{4}"))*1}), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image]